# Not able bind the data to class variables while using success call back of $.get in typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, knockout.js, observable

I am using `TypeScript`. I am trying to bind the response from rest API to a variable in a `ViewModel` like below:

```
export class TestListViewModel {

  public personItems: KnockoutObservableArray<Person>;

  constructor() {
        this.personItems = ko.observableArray([]);

        this.person1 = new Person();
        this.person1.name = ko.observable<string>("Test 1");
        this.person1.ssnId = ko.observable<string>("1234");
        this.personItems.push(this.person1);

       //If i put a debugger here and see the "this.personItems()" in console 
       //I can see 1 object in personItems

        $.get("https://somerestapi/api/TestLists", 
             (data: any) => {
                 for (var index in data) {
                  this.person1 = new Person();
                  this.person1.name = ko.observable<string>(data[index].name);
                  this.person1.ssnId = ko.observable<string>(data[index].ssnId);
                  this.personItems.push(this.person1);
                  //If i put a debugger here and see the "this.personItems()" in console 
                 **//Now i am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: this.personItems is not a function"**
                 //If i do only "this.personItems" it is giving as "Undefined"
             } 
        });

  } //end of constructor

} //end of class
```

Please see my comments in the code. When I am giving the data to `personItems` variable in constructor then I can see the data in the variable. But when I am doing the same in success cal back of `$.get` then data is not getting added to `personItems` variable. Why?

Could some one please help me what is wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: wrap it in a callback?

Comment: Constructor **should** _immediately_ return a valid, usable object. Calling an async code inside a constructor is generally a bad practice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the scoping problems with javascript.

Can you try following code?

```
export class TestListViewModel {

  public personItems: KnockoutObservableArray<Person>;

  constructor() {
    const self = this;
        self.personItems = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.person1 = new Person();
        self.person1.name = ko.observable<string>("Test 1");
        self.person1.ssnId = ko.observable<string>("1234");
        self.personItems.push(self.person1);

       //If i put a debugger here and see the "self.personItems()" in console 
       //I can see 1 object in personItems

        $.get("https://somerestapi/api/TestLists", 
             (data: any) => {
                 for (var index in data) {
                  self.person1 = new Person();
                  self.person1.name = ko.observable<string>(data[index].name);
                  self.person1.ssnId = ko.observable<string>(data[index].ssnId);
                  self.personItems.push(self.person1);
                  //If i put a debugger here and see the "self.personItems()" in console 
                 **//Now i am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: self.personItems is not a function"**
                 //If i do only "self.personItems" it is giving as "Undefined"
             } 
        });

  } //end of constructor

}
```

Comment: Great Avinash!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the entire code for the class? Is `personItems` accessed anywhere outside of the constructor? I would guess that there is something else that is manipulating `personItems` after `$get` is called and before it returns, and setting its size to 0.

Comment: Thanks for th equick reply Andrew. I edited my question. And also i created one more variable personItems1 in class and used that in success call back of $.get. Now i am also getting error as "Uncaught TypeError: this.personItems is not a function" when i am doing this.personItems1 (). And getting "Undefined" when i am doing this.personItems1.